# why doesn't my screen manager won't work with kivy language alone and needs python?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Why does this work perfectly but I had to add screen widgets from python explicitly

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
class start(Screen):
  pass
class filexp(Screen):
  pass
class shuff(ScreenManager):
  pass
  
sty='''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<shuff>:
    transition:FadeTransition()
    start:
    filexp:
<start>:
    name:'main'
    Button:
        text:'what'
        on_release:app.root.current='exp'
<filexp>:
    name:'exp'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            on_release:app.root.current='main'
          
'''
Builder.load_string(sty)
class a(App):
  def build(self):
    x=shuff()
    x.add_widget(start())
    x.add_widget(filexp())
    return(x)
a().run()
```

But this only shows black screen despite having added screens to screen manager in kivy language

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
class start(Screen):
  pass
class filexp(Screen):
  pass
class shuff(ScreenManager):
  pass
  
sty='''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<shuff>:
    transition:FadeTransition()
    start:
    filexp:
<start>:
    name:'main'
    Button:
        text:'what'
        on_release:app.root.current='exp'
<filexp>:
    name:'exp'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            on_release:app.root.current='main'
          
'''
Builder.load_string(sty)
class a(App):
  def build(self):
    return(shuff())
a().run()
```

Is there something I have done wrong or is it some glitch as I'm running interpreter in mobile with pydroid app

Comment: Make sure your class names begin with capital letters, kv uses this to distinguish them from kv properties. In this case I think it's added properties with those names instead of the child widgets you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much inclement , it worked out.. amazing I 
got answered so quickly

Answer (score 0):

Made all class names to begin with capital letter, it worked fine

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
class Start(Screen):
  pass
class Filexp(Screen):
  pass
class Shuff(ScreenManager):
  pass
  
sty='''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<Shuff>:
    transition:FadeTransition()
    Start:
    Filexp:
<Start>:
    name:'main'
    Button:
        text:'what'
        on_release:app.root.current='exp'
<Filexp>:
    name:'exp'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            on_release:app.root.current='main'
          
'''
Builder.load_string(sty)
class a(App):
  def build(self):
    return(Shuff())
a().run()
```